# how do I get the type of the file in flask?

Tags: python, file, flask

I have to differenciate between two types of files (RIS-file and bibTex file).

I know how to get the complete filename (example: `uploadedfilename = file.filename`). But I need to get only the type of the file and my current code only gives me something like this: "`uploadedfilename: test.ris`". 
Is there a way to get only the file type so that I could do something like this:

`if(filetype=="ris"): 
     do some stuff`?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
filetype = file.filename.split('.')[-1]
```